# How to execute netcat command from python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to execute Altair Accelerator, previously known as `NetworkComputer (NC)`, through python script.
My shell command is: `nc run -q vnc01 run -C TEST -wl -I -r+ CORES/32 -r+ RAM/150000 -- /bin/tcsh`
I have tried this code:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['nc run',' -q vnc01  run -C TEST -wl -I -r+ CORES/32 -r+ RAM/150000 -- /bin/tcsh'], stdout=f)
```

Returned the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "nc.py", line 11, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(['nc run',' -q vnc01 run -C TEST -wl -I -r+ CORES/32 -r+ RAM/150000 -- /bin/tcsh'], stdout=f)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory Exit 1
```

Comment: why python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the command arguments properly:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([
    'nc',
    'run', '-q', 'vnc01',
    'run', '-C', 'TEST',
    '-wl', '-I',
    '-r+', 'CORES/32',
    '-r+', 'RAM/150000',
    '--',
    '/bin/tcsh'
], stdout=f)
```